# Can a shutter booster lens speed up the shortest shutter time on my DSLR?

Tags: lens, nikon, shutter-speed

Is there any shutter speed booster lens available for Nikon 5300.

Currently Nikon 5300 supports 1/4000.

What if I would like to increase the shutter speed to 1/8000 or more....

Is there any specific shutter speed booster lens available in the market?

Comment: lens has nothing to do with shutter speed.Shutter speed is camera mechanism it is what it is and will have no effect.

Comment: What are you trying to do that requires 1/8000s shutter speed? I suspect there's a different solution which actually exists :-)

Comment: How about taking a pic of a moving car....or a dancing group..... what do you suggest?

Comment: 1/1000s would be fine for both those cases. 1/4000s is overkill. 1/8000s would definitely be overkill.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, then why do we have 1/8000 in D7000 & D800 series...

Comment: Shooting with a fast lens wide open in bright sunlight is probably the most common use case, but others do exist.

Comment: I didn't got the solid reason of down voting as I asked this question is to understand/know if any thing can be done with shutter speed...even though it may be worthless for downvoter but may be informative based on reply for someone else....

Comment: That would be better asked on chat or meta but my 2p (I didn't downvote, but got quite close): firstly, you haven't actually said what problem you're trying to solve. You've jumped in half way through with "I need 1/8000s shutter speed", but it turns out your use case was just action photography, which doesn't need 1/8000s. Secondly, there's a lack of research here - what made you believe a device called a "shutter speed booster lens" that does what you say exists? (Links please!)

Comment: I searched a lot on it but didn't got much information that if we can do something with the existing shutter speed. I was under impression that any speed booster/some other device can raise the shutter speed..... May be I didn't construct the question properly out of curiosity....but a minor edit could have done that....instead of downvoting

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are hoping for.  The shutter is not in the lens, but rather in the camera.  A lens can't increase the maximum shutter speed of the camera itself unless it had it's own independent shutter.  I'm not aware of any such lenses.

Speed Boosting adapters are not used to increase the maximum shutter speed of the camera, but rather to focus more of the light gathered by a full frame lens on to a crop sensor, thus allowing a faster supported shutter speed to be used.  For example, perhaps rather than needing 1/60th second for an exposure, the same exposure can be accomplished in 1/120 seconds.

Comment: Could you please suggest any speed boosting lenses then

Comment: A speed booster is a specific type of adapter that goes between a full frame lens and the camera.  It doesn't do what you were originally looking for.  It will not let you take a 1/8000 photo, but rather allow you to take a 1/4000 photo in light that originally would have required you to use a 1/2000 exposure.

Answer (score 4):

I guess you are confused with term "faster lens". It basically a high quality glass with very small f number say f/1.2. The use of this kinda aperture is in low light conditions. When you can bring down the f number to gather more light, it helps you choose a faster shutter speed, you can pick a shutter speed you camera is designed for in your case no matter what lens you chose you can not pick a shutter speed faster than 1/4000.For example while shooting in night with a lens having maximum aperture f/3.4 and to shoot you need 1/60th of shutter speed. Choosing a faster lens (lens with maximum aperture say f/1.4) you will get the same shot but with a faster shutter speed it could be 1/200 or whatever. In this sense you can say a lens is faster over the other.

Comment: Oh! And I was under impression that we can make shutter speed faster with some external lens/device....thanks for clarification.....